# Class constants of the type being def'd

Tags: python, class, singleton

In Python, is there any to declare class members of the type being declared?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.one = a
        self.two = b

    ZERO = Foo(0, 0)
    ONE = Foo(0, 1)
```

The problem seems to arise from the fact that the class `Foo` isn't completely def'd at the time of evaluation for `Foo.ZERO` and `Foo.ONE` - is there any way to overcome this while maintaining the form of `Foo.MEMBER`?

Comment: Can you explain why you would need to do this?

Comment: I assume the goal is an enumerated type? Analogous to Java's `enum` syntax, for instance.

Comment: This actually is not for an enumeration (although it'd be an excellent application of this!), but rather constants such as `java.lang.BigInteger.ZERO` or the like. I'm writing strictly numerical classes for applications in operations research - [PyPLEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPLEX), if you will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
class Enum(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b): 
        self.one = a
        self.two = b 

    def __metaclass__(name, bases, dict):
        cls = type(name, bases, dict)
        cls.ZERO = cls(0, 0)
        cls.ONE = cls(0, 1)
        return cls
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.one = a
        self.two = b

Foo.ZERO = Foo(0, 0)
Foo.ONE = Foo(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be impossible! (Maybe I'm not think clear)
If it is possible, then this 'cause, 
    Foo has the member ZERO which also generates Foo, and again....

I think if the class can be produced, the python also alert you or something else.